# Specify a start value in a for loop

Tags: java, loops

I am doing my for loop below in Java. I have a default value for the number that the user starts out with, which is 100. I dedicated a field for the user to input there own number in, which would change the default value in the constructor.

Anyway, I want my for loop to take that number that they put in and start to increment it until they reach 100. The loop runs fine but it starts at 53 and it increments I don't know why. Can someone tell me please? 
My code is below.

```
defaultvaluenumber = userinput; 
for(defaultvaluenumber = userinput; userinput < 100; userinput++)
{
   System.out.println("Your current number incremented is: " + userinput);  
}
```

Comment: The loop runs from `defaultvaluenumber` up to 100. How can we help here? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Please see how to create a [mcve]. We do not know why your loop starts at `53`. There is no 53 in your question's code

Comment: Agreed with @cricket_007, please be more concrete

Comment: The line before the for loop is unnecessary. `userinput` must have been `53` or `'5'`. Show how useriput is assigned.

Comment: Please tell us what are you passing as userinput. Your question is bit unclear. Agreed with @cricket_007

Comment: Guys what I have is a default variable that holds the value of a 100. I want to do a check for the users input ok and without much complex code such as "java.util.Scanner" (an example). Then depending on their input I want to start incrementing that particular until it reaches 100. However, I tried a while and for loop and they all start from 53. I checked all my equations and everything there is no 53 anywhere.

Comment: @NickLow add more details about the previous code.. We cannot imagine what you did. Edit your question with details!

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me please? My code is below.

```
defaultvaluenumber = userinput; 
for(defaultvaluenumber = userinput; unserinput < 100; userinput++)
{
   System.out.println("Your current number incremented is: " + userinput);  
}
```

**Yes, for induction `userinput` contains the value `53`. That's the reason!**

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you are saying about fields and constructors, but based on your later comments, the problem seems to be coming from elsewhere.

Here is what I think you are asking.

> I want my for loop to take that number that they put in

```
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a starting value: ");
int userinput = sc.nextInt();
```

> and start to increment it until they reach 100

```
while(userinput < 100) {
    System.out.println("Your current number incremented is: " + userinput++);  
}
```